# JPos - ISO8583 Messages TLV Fields

Tags: java, iso8583, jpos

I'm constructing a simple e-purchase financial message using jpos library, i'm using a generic packager to pack my message fields, the problem occurs at field 48 which is a TLV Field.

here are the packaging parameters for field 48.

```
        <isofieldpackager id="48"
            name="Additional Private Data" 
            length="999"
            class="org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLLBINARY"
            emitBitmap="false" 
            tagMapper="org.jpos.iso.packager.TTTDecimalTagMapper" 
            packager="org.jpos.iso.packager.GenericTaggedFieldsPackager">

            <!--  -->
            <isofield id="1" length="8" name="PSP Identifier" class="ma.XXY.net.merkit.utils.IFA_TTLLBINARY2"/>

            <!--  -->
            <isofield id="2" length="8" name="Ecommerce Acquirer Identifier" class="ma.XXY.net.merkit.utils.IFA_TTLLBINARY2"/>

            <!--  -->
            <isofield id="3" length="3" name="Buyer Country Code" class="ma.XXY.net.merkit.utils.IFA_TTLLBINARY2" />

            <!--  -->
            <isofield id="4" length="20" name="Buyer Card Brand" class="ma.XXY.net.merkit.utils.IFA_TTLLBINARY2" />

            <!--  -->
            <isofield id="5" length="24" name="Buyer IP Address" class="ma.XXY.net.merkit.utils.IFA_TTLLBINARY2" />

            <!--  -->
            <isofield id="6" length="30" name="Buyer email Address" class="ma.XXY.net.merkit.utils.IFA_TTLLBINARY2" />

            <!--  -->
            <isofield id="7" length="14" name="Buyer Phone Number" class="ma.XXY.net.merkit.utils.IFA_TTLLBINARY2" />

            <isofield id="8" length="6" name="Merchant Operation Reference" class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR" />
            <isofield id="9" length="3" name="One Click Indicator" class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
            <isofield id="10" length="12" name="ISC INTERNET PIN" class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
            <isofield id="11" length="3" name="One Click Indicator" class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>
            <isofield id="12" length="12" name="ISC INTERNET PIN" class="org.jpos.iso.IF_CHAR"/>

            <!--  -->
            <isofield id="13" length="12" name="One Click Indicator" class="ma.XXY.net.merkit.utils.IFA_TTLLBINARY2"/>

            <!--  -->
            <isofield id="14" length="1" name="ISC INTERNET PIN" class="ma.XXY.net.merkit.utils.IFA_TTLLBINARY2"/>

        </isofieldpackager>
```

**IFA_TTLLBINARY2.java**

```
        public class IFA_TTLLBINARY2 extends ISOTagBinaryFieldPackager {

            public IFA_TTLLBINARY2() {
                super(0,null, BcdPrefixer.LLL, NullPadder.INSTANCE,
                        LiteralBinaryInterpreter.INSTANCE, BcdPrefixer.LL);
            }

            public IFA_TTLLBINARY2 (int len, String description) {
                super(len, description, BcdPrefixer.LLL, NullPadder.INSTANCE,
                        LiteralBinaryInterpreter.INSTANCE, BcdPrefixer.LL);
           }
        }
```

**main.java**

```
    ISOMsg authISOMsg = new ISOMsg();
    ISOMsg authISOMsgResp;
    QMUX qMux;
    IServicesUtils service = new ServiceUtilsImpl();

    logger.info("Initiating Authorization Request for Simple ePurchase Transaction : 11001122222");

    // To be used in header
    String stan = service.generateSTAN();

    // HEADER
    String acquirerTimeOut = service
            .getValuesFromPropertiesFile(new String[] { IConstants.ACQUIRER_MSG_TIMEOUT }, "parameters.properties")
            .get(IConstants.ACQUIRER_MSG_TIMEOUT).toString();

    String issuerTimeOut = service
            .getValuesFromPropertiesFile(new String[] { IConstants.ISSUER_MSG_TIMEOUT }, "parameters.properties")
            .get(IConstants.ISSUER_MSG_TIMEOUT).toString();

    authISOMsg.setHeader(("001" + issuerTimeOut + DateUtils.getHeaderFieldIso(new Date(), stan)).getBytes());

    try {
        // MTI
        authISOMsg.setMTI(IsoConstants.ISO_AUTH_REQUEST_MSG_MTI);

        authISOMsg.set(14, "0819");

        // Merchant Type - not existing in mpi response
        authISOMsg.set(18, "3306");

        // POS Entry Mode
        authISOMsg.set(22, IsoConstants.ISO_AUTH_REQUEST_POS_ENTRY_MODE);

        // POS Condition code
        authISOMsg.set(25,IsoConstants.ISO_AUTH_REQUEST_POS_CONDITION_CODE);

        // Card Acceptor Terminal Identification
        authISOMsg.set(41,"BX023350");

        // Merchant ID
        authISOMsg.set(42, service.reduceMerchantIDLength("*****"));

        //
        authISOMsg.set("48.1","PSP_001");
        authISOMsg.set("48.2","ACQ_002");
        authISOMsg.set("48.3","MAR");
        authISOMsg.set("48.4","VISA INTERNATIONAL");
        authISOMsg.set("48.5","10.0.0.136");
        authISOMsg.set("48.6","*****");
        authISOMsg.set("48.7","******");

        // Currency
        authISOMsg.set(49,"840");

        Q2 scanner = new Q2();
        scanner.start();

        qMux = (QMUX) QMUX.getMUX("clientmux");

        authISOMsgResp = qMux.request(authISOMsg,
        Integer.parseInt(acquirerTimeOut));
        if (authISOMsgResp != null) {
            System.out.println(authISOMsgResp.getString(2));
        }
```

The main code above represents a Financial msg containing some fields, the problem that i have occurs at **field 48**.

The error below throws the following exception.

```
    Nested:org.jpos.iso.ISOException: Error reading deploy\packager\basic-packager.xml (org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:basic-packager.xml; 
    lineNumber: 114; columnNumber: 64; Attribute "tagMapper" must be declared for element type "isofieldpackager").
```

Comment: The problem seems to be that tagMapper is not defined in the dtd, can you share the beginning of the xml packager definition so we know wich dtd are you referring to?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE isopackager PUBLIC
        "-//jPOS/jPOS Generic Packager DTD 1.0//EN"
        "http://jpos.org/dtd/generic-packager-1.0.dtd">

Comment: Also which version of jpos are you using?

Comment: jpos version 2.0.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need to use the [generic-subtag-packager.dtd](https://github.com/jpos/jPOS/blob/master/jpos/src/main/resources/org/jpos/iso/packager/generic-subtag-packager.dtd) to validate your xml packager definition.

You can copy that file in the same directory as your xml and substitute the doctype definition for this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE isopackager SYSTEM "generic-subtag-packager.dtd">
```

I Hope this solve your problem.

Comment: do you have an example i could consult ?

Comment: I added the example doctype definition in the answer. But I don't have a working example of generic sub type packager, since I've never used it, but your problem is strictly xml based

Comment: i get this error after your recommended update.   **Document root element "isopackager", must match DOCTYPE root "document"**

Comment: I corrected the example, it would be easier if I could check your packager definition, but I can't because you didn't share it completely.

Comment: how can i customize the tag value, for example field 48.1 tag is P01 field 48.2 tag is P02 field 48.3 tag is P03......

Comment: Hi @SoufianeRabii that would be another question for which unfortunately  I don't have the answer. If you mean to change the value for using in ISOMsg.getString("48.1") I just think you cannot, since plain ISOMsgs fields are numeric. And the string "48.1" is just the concatenation of field.subfield.